# What's the easiest way to produce an X Hz sound wave in Java?

Tags: java, audio, waveform

It would also be great if it was fairly easy to export the wave so that it later can be drawn (visualized using for example Canvas).

To clarify:
I want to be able to **hear** a X Hz wave, and preferably **draw** it.

Comment: You want to make a wav file or a picture of a wave?

Comment: I clarified the question somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (double t = 0.0; t < maxTime; t += dt)
{
  double value = amplitude*sin(2.0*Math.PI*frequency*t);
}
```

Put the values out to the wave format or plotting program of your choice.

Comment: Any recommendations as to what wave format to use to easily listen and save it?